# transit visa for Paris while traveling from Ukraine to the Dominican Republic and changing planes at CDG

Tags: visas, transit

Does a Ukrainian citizen need a transit visa for Paris while traveling from Ukraine to the Dominican Republic and changing planes at CDG?

Answer (score 1):

No, because Ukrainian citizens don’t need a visa to visit France in the first place (provided they hold a biometric passport). Additionally, it may well be that the passenger will stay airside without passing through immigration at all. Are there any special circumstances?